# Saving output plot in R with grid.grab() doesn't work

Tags: r, plot, graphics, r-grid

I've been trying to save multiple plot generated with the `meta` package in R, used to conduct meta-analysis, but I have some troubles. I need to save this plot to arrange them in a multiple plot figure.

Example data:

```
s <- data.frame(Study = paste0("Study", 1:15),
                event.e = sample(1:100, 15),
                n.e = sample(100:300, 15))
meta1 <- meta::metaprop(event = event.e, 
                  n= n.e, 
                  data=s,
                  studlab = Study)
```

Here is the code:

```
meta::funnel(meta1)
funnelplot <- grid::grid.grab()
```

I can see the figure in the "plot" tab in R Studio; However, if I search the `funnelplot` object in the environment it say that is a "NULL" type, and obviously trying to recall that doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works fine for me. `class(funnelplot)` returns `[1] "gTree" "grob"  "gDesc"` and `funnelplot` returns `gTree[GRID.gTree.1053]`. Try restarting R.

Comment: @RonakShah Hmm, it could also be due to the example data that I added; maybe OP's data causes the problem. OP, can you add a small dataset with which the problem is reproducible, or test if you also have the problem with the example data I provided?

Comment: @Laterow yeah of course! I used the exact code that you provide (besides, thank you for that!), and get the same problem (NULL object, even if I type class(funnelplot) get "NULL" as output). I've also tried restarting R - same.

Comment: Note that I have tried the code also on another machine that run R Studio and get the same issue!